# linux command for removing duplicate values

Tags: linux

I have 2 files
file1 which contains

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

file2 contains

```
4,5,6,7,8
```

output should be in such a way that new file assume it as file3 should contain

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
```

and not only that if contents in file1 and file2 changes like

file1 new contents

```
10,11,12,13,14
```

file2 new contents

```
13,14,15,16,17,18
```

after merging file3 should should contain below values

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
```

I have tried several commands like sort, uniq, cat etc but it haven't worked

Comment: `touch file3; cat file1 file2 file3 | sort | uniq` ? You will need to translate the commas to newlines. `sed` or `tr` will do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands like `sort` and `uniq` work on lines.

All you have to do is convert commas to newlines, do `sort -u` or `uniq` and then convert the newlines back to commas, e.g.

```
$ cat a
1,2,3,4,5
$ cat b
4,5,6,7,8
$ cat a b | tr ',' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ','
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
```

You may find [Set Operations in the Unix Shell](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/set-operations-in-unix-shell/) helpful.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanq for your reply 
but I am getting errors the output is not in proper format

Comment: @VenkatKrishna I gave you an idea and an example. Try using what you know to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want merge result to file3:

```
cat file1 file2 | sed s/,/\\n/g | sort  -u | tr "\\n" "," >> file3
```